# How to Avoid page being reloaded after submit button in @html.BeginForm() in RAZOR MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have MVC3 razor form where i am using :

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("SaveTitanVlanConnectivityRequest", "SST", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "submitConnectivityRequest", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

I dont want to reload the page after submit form.

```
 <button id="btnSubmit" class="button" type="submit">
                    Save and Proceed</button>
```

Comment: this has very little to do with the razor and more to do with how the browser interprets HTML. The question is what do you want to do after submit button is clicked? if not a page reload / Form post?

Comment: I want to post a form with some fields then dont want the current page should be reloaded..beacsue i have already written some logic on documen.ready() and after that page reload this logic is failing

Comment: @ANUJ then use ajax request

Comment: @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveTitanVlanConnectivityRequest", "SST", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }, new { target = "_self" }))
     will this line of code should work and i dont know if i will using this code and may be it is working then howmuch this code will be relevant.?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery in your project you can use the [submit handler](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

```
$('form').submit(function(e/*event data*/){
 /*do anything you want to*/
})
```

Comment: Thanks..it is working for me after AJAX. but one issue is like i have Upload button inside that form which is used to upload an attachment i dont want to reload in this case too..      <input type="button" value="Upload" class="button" name="saveMode" id="btnUploadFileTitanVlan" />